# how to get form data from http post headers with server-side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, webforms

I am receiving a callback from MS sign-in for azure active directory. The post contains an id token in the headers, need to read this into a string variable on server side.

I can see the data in chrome dev tools under network/headers/formdata. I have iterated through headers collection - it is not there. How the hell do you access this data?

Code used to display headers (actually using vb.net, but it is such a small fraction of the market now that I am posting for c#, which I can readily translate if nec.):

```
Dim loop1, loop2 As Integer
Dim arr1(), arr2() As String
Dim coll As NameValueCollection

' Load Header collection into NameValueCollection object.
coll = Request.Headers

' Put the names of all keys into a string array.
arr1 = coll.AllKeys
For loop1 = 0 To arr1.GetUpperBound(0)
    txtOutput.Text += "Key: " & arr1(loop1) & vbCrLf
    arr2 = coll.GetValues(loop1)
    ' Get all values under this key.
    For loop2 = 0 To arr2.GetUpperBound(0)
        txtOutput.Text += "Value " & CStr(loop2) & ": " & Server.HtmlEncode(arr2(loop2)) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next loop2
Next loop1
```

I was expecting to find this data in the headers collection, but it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. The answer is in your question. Use `coll = Request.Form` instead of `coll = Request.Headers`.